# Expected input with 32 bytes (256 bits), found 48 bytes

Tags: ink, wasm, pallet-contracts, solidity

I have a solidity smart contract that I compile using Solang to substrate wasm.

```
contract Pool {
address xxx;
constructor(address _test){
  xxx = _test;
}

function callFoo(address _test) external returns (bool){
  _test.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("flip()"));
  return true;
}
```

}

But I received the error trying deploy the contract using polkadot js org

[image]

How to specify the substrate wasm contract address?

Comment: Check the substrate version with which solang is compatible, this is one of the reasons, another one is, you need to optimize the solidity code before compiling which remix already provides but I don't know does solang has it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solang works with Parity Substrate 3.0. Note that for recent Substrate Version, **cross-contract calls** as well as **using address type as function argument** or return values **ARE NOT SUPPORTED**. We are currently **working on** fixing any regressions.

https://solang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/targets/substrate.html